# Using Angular Forms, How do I make form invalid if they uncheck an input?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Using Angular 5, I've tried a few variations.  If I set it to the checkbox to `ngModel="iAgreeToTOS" required` it only seems to work after I interact with the checkbox unclicking it and clicking it.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="ft-mail"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ngModel required email >
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-offset-1">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked>
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="pl-2">I agree to <a>terms and conditions</a></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <app-async-button submitText="Banana" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid || !this.iAgreeToTOS" [submit]="register" [loading]="loading"></app-async-button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try initializing model value to false?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by binding the `ngModel` and `name` attribute as this:

```html
<form #registrationForm>
  <!-- -->
  <input type="checkbox" ngModel name="iAgreeToTOS" required>
  <!-- -->
</form>
```

Also if you want to show validation errors, you need to remember to mark `#iAgreeToTOS="ngModel"` and the same equivalent for your other field.

---

As a *sidenote*, not related to problem, but I would suggest moving to reactive form. You have better control of your form with that. If you would consider it, read on, if not, quit reading :D  Here's a sample for you on the reactive approach:

```ts
registrationForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    agreeToTerms: [false, Validators.pattern('true')]
  });
```

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm">
  <input formControlName="email" />
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="agreeToTerms" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks will consider reactive - however to close the loop on the template version - doing it that way with the ngmodel - it doesn't consider it to have been been valid until the user clicks on the checkbox and interacts with it - even if it was checked by default initially.  Only when they cycle it off and back on is it triggering valid.  BTW when you use the ngmodel keyword without explicitly setting it- what is the default backing property it gets bound to .. in this case `this.iAgreeToTOS`?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular exist two ways to do Forms:

- Template driven Forms
- Dynamic Forms

[Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

**What you have above is nothing of both!**

With dynamic forms you can mark a form as dirty / valid / touched and you can then block or disable the submit button.

With template driven forms you can add a variable to the input then look to the added css with `className` to know which css class is active ng-dirty / ng-valid / ng-touched or you can check in your component the model, then block or disable the submit button if the state is not ok.